# Can't build with expo eas build - Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information

Tags: javascript, react-native, gradle, expo, expo-build

Help needed, I'm trying to build my expo app with eas build -p android, it is showing the below "

> 

[stderr] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[stderr] * Where:
[stderr] Settings file '/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/settings.gradle' line: 3
[stderr] * What went wrong:
[stderr] A problem occurred evaluating settings 'voteboothapp'.
[stderr] > Could not read script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-unimodules/gradle.groovy' as it does not exist.
[stderr] * Try:
[stderr] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[stderr] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[stderr] BUILD FAILED in 14s
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

"

I have not been stuck here for more than a week since most of the help I am seeing online are pointing me to android studio which I have followed and hence got more error trying to set up android studio, please is there anyone who can help me with ways I can build my simple expo app without having to use android studio, the classic expo build service worked flawlessly before the advent of eas-cli, the reason I have been using expo is to avoid android studio but now they are forcing devs to go back to android studio.

Edit - also I have tried expo doctor expo doctor --fix-dependencies and still not working